# Do the isomorphism's of groups form an equivalence relation on the class of all groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

An isomorphism is simply a bijective homomorphism. How would one show that isomorphism's are symmetric, reflexive, and transitive?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews do I simply show $f(g_1*g_2)= f(g_1) \cdot f(g_2) = j(g_1*g_2)= j(g_1) \cdot j(g_2) -> j(g_1*g_2)= j(g_1) \cdot j(g_2) = f(g_1*g_2) = f(g_1) \cdot f(g_2)$ 
for isomorphisms f and j?

Comment: ^^ not sure why thats incorrectly formatting. *for isomorphisms f and j

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relation being considered is: if $G,H$ are groups, then $G\sim H$ if there is an isomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

**Symmetry**

This amounts to showing that if there is an isomorphism $f: G\to H$, then there is also an isomorphism $g: H\to G$. To construct $g$, we note that since $f$ is bijective, we can consider the inverse function $f^{-1}$, which is also bijective. It remains to show that $f^{-1}$ is a homomorphism from $H$ to $G$.

Suppose we have two elements $h_1,h_2\in H$. Since $f$ is a surjection, we can write $h_1=f(g_1)$ and $h_2=f(g_2)$ for some elements $g_1,g_2\in G$. Since $f$ is a homomorphism, we then have that

$$f^{-1}(h_1h_2)=f^{-1}(f(g_1)f(g_2))=f^{-1}(f(g_1g_2))=g_1g_2=f^{-1}(h_1)f^{-1}(h_2)$$

so $g:=f^{-1}$ works perfectly well as an isomorphism from $H$ to $G$.

**Reflexivity**

We need to show that there is an isomorphism from any group to itself. This is easy: just take the identity mapping. It is very clearly bijective, and the homomorphism property is very easy to verify since elements are simply mapped to themselves.

**Transitivity**

This amounts to showing that if there are isomorphisms $f: G\to H$ and $g: H\to K$, then there is also an isomorphism $h: G\to K$. The easiest thing to try (which indeed works) is to take $h:= g\circ f$. If you already know that the composition of bijections is a bijection, then it is clear that this definition gives a bijection from $G$ to $K$. You just need to show that this definition of $h$ gives a homomorphism. This follows from the fact that $f$ and $g$ are homomorphisms:

$$h(g_1g_2)=g(f(g_1g_2))=g(f(g_1)f(g_2))=g(f(g_1))g(f(g_2))=h(g_1)h(g_2)$$

Comment: Can u provide an example of transitivity?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are a little confused about what the relation is. The set is the class of all groups, and two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic (denoted $G_1 \cong G_2$) if there exists an isomorphism $f:G_1 \to G_2$. You want to show that being isomorphic is an equivalence relation.

- Reflexivity: show that any group isomorphic to itself
- Symmetry: show that $G_1 \cong G_2$ implies $G_2 \cong G_1$.
- Transitivity: show that $G_1 \cong G_2$ and $G_2 \cong G_3$ together imply $G_1 \cong G_3$.